# Modern art for a child

Tags: books, imaginative-play

I am looking for a collection of images of modern art painting - Pollack, Kandinsky, Chagall, Picasso, Braque, etc. The objective is to provide some additional stimulation for my child (5 y.o.), who is quite creative in drawing and creating collages. There are, of course, plenty of books on the subject, but I am not particularly interested in long technical explanations or over-complicated artistic concepts - just enabling her to observe original images and approaches. On the other hand, I would like to show her real artistic works, rather than pictures "in the style of X" designed specifically for children (we have a few books like *Three little pigs* in the style of Kandinsky, but I think the combination serves poorly as to the story, as to the painting style.)

I will appreciate recommendations.

Comment: You could try to obtain an exhibition catalogue for an exhibition at a museum of one or several of the artists you are looking for. They typically have photographs of the artworks.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [24th Kandinsky](https://sciartica.itch.io/the-24th-kandinsky). Its a free game you can download based on the works of Kandinsky.

It consists of PDF and text files (no executable files), so is compatible with almost any device.